# Looping through array object to check value match only works for first iteration, subsequent iterations failing

Tags: arrays, typescript, for-loop, object, ionic4

I have an object in a quiz application that stores the question number and the user answer. I have a function that loops through the object to check if the question number exists in the object. If it does the user answer is updated and if not a new entry is made.

My problem is the for the first entry I can add, check if question number exists and update user answers but for all other entries it fails to match the question number so all updates appear as new entries in the object.

This is my debug output:

```
0: {questionNo: 0, answer: Array(2)}
1: {questionNo: 2, answer: Array(2)}
2: {questionNo: 2, answer: Array(2)}
```

There should only be one entry of 2 in question number (questionNo) as the function should check if the question number already exists and update array would be. The function only works with the data in index 0 and all others question numbers are not matched and become new entries.

The function is:

```
public answers: any  = [];

public count = 0;


constructor(){

}

addItem(item, item2){
this.answers.push({
    questionNo: item,
    answer: item2
});
}

checkIfQnAnswered(num){
    
    for(let i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++) 
    {
        //console.log(i);
        if(this.answers[i].questionNo == num)
        {
             console.log("Question number exists at " + i);
            //this.count++;
            //return this.count;
            return true;
        }
        else if(this.answers[i].questionNo != num)
        {
            console.log("Question number does not exisit");
            //this.count++;
            //return this.count;                
            return false;
        }
    }
    

}

updateQnAnswered(item, item2){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++) 
    {
        if(this.answers[i].questionNo == item)
        {
           // this.count++;
            //this.answers.splice(i, 1);
            this.answers[i].questionNo = item;
            this.answers[i].answer = item2;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi, the question is quite confusing. What is the type of `this.answers`, is it an object or an array? In the top lines, you said you are looping through the object, but from the function, its seems it is an array. Could you please provide some sample input for `this.answers` along with actual output and desired output? The debug output does not seem quite helpful.

Comment: Hi @ShivamSingla, thanks for the response. It is an array. I have provided the full code for the array declaration , the code for adding items and updating. When a user answers a question (in this case selecting which statements are true or false) the particular question number and an array of his selected answers are pushed to the array. if the question number exists, the array of answers is updated and if the question number does not exist, a new question number and answer array pair are pushed to the array. My problem is the question number check only works with the data in index 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work. The problem with your code was that, when it was index 0, there was no match. So the `if` condition was false and `else if` becomes true. Next the code in `else if` block executes and immediately returns (this breaks the loop, stops the function execution and returns `false`). So the loop runs only one time for the example provided. Actually, the loop will run only one time for any value of `num` and `this.answers`, as the if-else ladder is exhaustive and both have `return` statement in them.

```js
checkIfQnAnswered(num) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++) {
        if(this.answers[i].questionNo === num) {
            // found first match, now return true
            console.log("Question number exists at " + i);
            //this.count++;
            //return this.count;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // we are here, means no match was found
    return false
}
```

In the above code, the functions return `true` when the loop finds first match; `false` otherwise when there is no match.